# Using Rails, what is the best method to set a changing default date on date_select field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby/Rails and this is my first question. I'm working on a finance program that has a months model and a transaction model with a month having many transactions. I am also using the awesome_nested_fields gem found here: https://github.com/lailsonbm/awesome_nested_fields.

Everything works great but when I'm adding a new transaction, the date defaults to today. I would like it to default to the date of the last transaction that was added to the current month. For example, if I added a transaction with a date of 5/15/2012, the next transaction should default to that date. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: could you post or paste (http://pastie.org/) some of your code?

Answer (score 1):

so lets say you're doing something like this in your controller:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @transaction = current_user.transactions.build
  end
end
```

Change that to be:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @transaction = current_user.transactions.build(date: current_user.next_transaction_date)
  end
end
```

Then in your user, you can figure out the date to use

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def last_transaction_in_current_month
    transactions.where("date >= ?", Date.today.beginning_of_month).order("date desc").first
  end

  def next_transaction_date
    return Date.today if last_transaction_in_current_month.nil?
    last_transaction_in_current_month
  end
end
```